# Angular resize dynamically a property in the DOM

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, window-resize

i have an issue about resizing my items on the screen in Angular, if someone change the window size of the browser. Here my Code:

// TS File

```
height: number = 2.5;
objHeight:number;
screenHeight:number = window.innerHeight;

public createNumber() {
this.objHeight = this.screenHeight / this.height;
}


ngOnInit(){
this.createNumber();
}

onResize(event) {
event.target.innerWidth;
console.log(event);
this.objHeight = this.screenHigh / 2.5;
}
```

// HTML File

```
<div *ngFor="let datas of data; let i = index" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">  


        <ul id='list'>
            <li class='list-item' [id]=d atas.id [ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate('+rotateAngleArray[i]+'deg) translate(0,-'+objHeight+'px) rotate(-'+rotateAngleArray[i]+'deg)' }">

                <div class='label1'>
                    <img alt='notfound' class='img2' src='any picture'>
                </div>
                <div class='label2'>
                    {{ datas.name }}
                </div>
                <div class='label3'>
                    {{ datas.id }}
                </div>
                <div class='label4'>
                    {{ datas.rev }}
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The onResize(event) function is called always as i change the window size of the browser while the app is running. But how can i manage it to update automatically my objHeight at `[ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate('+rotateAngleArray[i]+'deg) translate(0,-'+objHeight+'px) rotate(-'+rotateAngleArray[i]+'deg)' }"` everytime i change the window size of the browser?

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: have you tried bringing in the ChangeDetectorRef and calling detectChanges()?  It seems like that might be outside of Angular's scope.

Comment: I don't see any problem with current way, are you asking for alternative solution?

Comment: @chrispy I donth know if thats what i need, cause the `onResize(event)` triggers already everytime i change the window size of the browser, but it just doesnt upgrade my `objHeight` in the HTML File

Comment: @PankajParkar My problem is that the `objHeight` property doesnt change/upgrade in the HTML file while running the app and resizing meanwhile the window size of the browser. the `onResize(event)` does get triggered by every window size change, but it doesnt change the value of `objHeight`.

Comment: Kamui, I understand that the function is called.  detectChanges might force your backing value to the view, which seems to be exactly your problem.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but in code you've provided but you're not changing the value of `screenHeight` property inside `onResize` method. So `objHeight` property never changes its value.

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski Wow, it was really the point. Im sry guys, i really tought Angular wouldnt upgrade the value in the html File after creating and i maybe had to two way Binding the property and so on... Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screeHeight-property never changes during the component lifecycle, you are just setting it once. Anyway the Observable way is cleaner:

```
import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
import {startWith, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
ojbHeight$:Observable<number>;
ngOnInit() {
     this.objHeight$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
       startWith(null), 
       map(this.getHeight.bind(this))
    );
}
getHeight() { return window.innerHeight/this.height; }
```

Template:

```
<div [style.height.px]="objHeight$|async"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i noticed i just set it once, was my first issue. But i also searched for a cleaner way to implement this, cause im new to Angular and dont know now the best solutions yet. Thx for your help, thats what i searched for :)

Comment: What is the value for `this.height` ?